# Workflow which adds the filename to excel

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have got a workflow (in sharepoint online) that starts when a file is added into a library. Now I want to parse the document name and add the name to an excel file. I read that I could do this maybe with the Web Services in SharePoint Designer. Any idea how I should approach this?

Cheers